# Maximum likelihood Estimation of three-parameter log-logistic distribution in R

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to estimate parameters from a three-parameter Log-logistic distribution in R. I have a code as follows:

```
nloglike <- function(p,y) {
 n <- length(y)
 alpha <- p[1];   beta <-p[2];gamma <-p[3];
if (alpha > 0 && y > gamma && beta >= 1)
{logl <- sum(log((beta/alpha)*((y-gamma)/alpha)^(beta - 1))-log(1+((y-
 gamma)/alpha)^beta))^2}  
 else { logl <- 10000 } 
return((logl))}

yy<-exp(data[,2])
sol<-optim(p=c(1,1,0),nloglike,method ="BFGS",y=yy,control=list(trace=0))$par
print(sol)
```

The code does not throw any errors, but the output is far different from what's expected. I would like to know what to consider when choosing the initial / starting values from the optim command. i.e. p=c(1,1,0)